# Am not able to scrape the content of a table from the following website using Selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, web-scraping

From the following site
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EhIMW8kQ/
After page loads tap "Strategy Tester -> List of Trades" tab.

There you can see a table and it's dynamically changing, is there any way to scrape that table content.

Comment: You can scrap the data but the data will change after some time. You'll have to periodically scrap the data to get the latest data.

Comment: I had tried it. But i got only First  6 Rows.

Comment: Please add the code block that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can scrap the table content by scrolling till the end of table is reached :
By applying recusion here you can achieve this :

(I am assuming that you have reached to "Strategy Tester -> List of Trades" tab.):
Below is the code :

```
package com.demo.core;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TableParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "J:\\STADIUM\\selenium-demo\\src\\main\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/EhIMW8kQ/");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any integer to continue : ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();

        // I have used Scanner here just to hold the execution until I reach "Strategy Tester -> List of Trades" tab manually
        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.report-content.trades .report-data .table-wrap table tbody"));
        WebElement tableView = driver.findElement(By.className("report-content"));
        int count = 0;

        printTableDataRecursively(rows, count, driver, tableView);
    }

    /** It will print the table data using recursion
     * @param rows First list of rows
     * @param count
     * @param driver
     * @param tableView scrollable table view element
     */
    public static void printTableDataRecursively(List<WebElement> rows, int count, WebDriver driver, WebElement tableView) {
        boolean bottomOfTableReached = checkIfBottomOfViewReached(driver, tableView); // checking if end of table is reached
        for (WebElement row : rows) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(row.getAttribute("textContent")); 
            if (count == rows.size() && !bottomOfTableReached) {
                count = 0;
                scrollToElement(driver, row); // scrolling to last row element from list of rows
                rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.report-content.trades .report-data .table-wrap table tbody")); // getting new list of rows
                rows.remove(0); // removing first row element because it was the last row from previous list of rows
                printTableDataRecursively(rows, count, driver,tableView);
            }
        }
    }

     /** It will check if scroll has reached to bottom of an HTML element that is scrollable.
     * @param driver
     * @param element 
     * @return true (if bottom reached) otherwise false
     */
    public static boolean checkIfBottomOfViewReached(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
         return  (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("if (arguments[0].scrollHeight == arguments[0].offsetHeight + arguments[0].scrollTop) { return true; } else { return false; }", element);
     }

     /** It will scroll to the given WebElement.
     * @param driver
     * @param element
     */
    public static void scrollToElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element);
        }

}
```

I am getting 291 rows in total (last 3 or 4 rows contains duplicate) and I think you can solve that by yourself.

**My point is just that you have to scroll and get rows data until end of table is reached.**

Just run this program and see the output in console.

Hope that helps you in achieving your goal.

Comment: Hi @dangi13, i tested your code in python and got an error when a new data in been added dynamically in the table, any suggestion to solve this?